# Render an external html page as body in your RoR project: Encoding::CompatibilityError

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, render

I want an external webpage rates.appiclife.com to be rendered in the applications <%=yield%>.

I tried this:

I placed the following method in pages_controller.rb

```
def fetch_url(url)
    r = Net::HTTP.get_response( URI.parse( url ) )
    if r.is_a? Net::HTTPSuccess
      r.body
    else
      nil
    end
  end
```

In the same file:

```
def showexternal
  @snippet = fetch_url "http://rates.appiclife.com/"
end
```

And in the showexternal.html.erb view/pages:

```
<%= @snippet %>
```

I get the following error: `incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT`

Is it even possible to do this? The thing is that those prices are updated and received in an excel file, so a lot of work to adapt them if I just place them in a html-table.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to parse the request response with Nokogiri into a string and then do whatever you want to with it.  You can find a quick tutorial here:

http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html